# Webpack - CommonsChunkPlugin (lib building), common.js not loading in parent app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am creating the UI component library in React...

My Webpack config have multiple entry points which result in multiple bundles eg:

[image]

Am using `CommonsChunkPlugin` which generates the common.js, which is shared code between other bundles.

In parent app (React app in which I want to consume UI lib) I do:

`import { Button } from 'ui-library/lib/Button';`

But this Results in:

```
webpackJsonp is not defined
```

Which means that common.js is not loaded. Here is my webpack plugins property value:

[image]

Am I missing something? IS common.js supposed to be loaded manually in the parent project? I expeted that importing the cmp is all which should be required, but maybe I am wrong, or I just missed something in the config...

Comment: I'm not certain if I'm understanding your problem correctly, but I can confirm that unless you have a separate plugin that modifies your HTML templates accordingly, you do have to manually include that `common.js` file that CommonsChunk generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should import common.js manually, as stated in the documentation :

> You must load the generated chunk before the entry point:

```
<script src="commons.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="entry.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Source : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/